# Video purchased from Apple is blacked out

Tags: macos, tv.app

I purchased and downloaded a video called "[Dreaming of a Jewish Christmas](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/dreaming-of-a-jewish-christmas/id1441435420)."  When I play it, audio works, and controls, mouse pointer, and captions are visible, but no picture—the rest of the screen is black.  Is there a fix for this?

NOTE: This has nothing to do with the Apple TV hardware.  This is using the app on a MacBook Pro with MacOS 13.0.1 (22A400).

Comment: The tag description says AppleTV+ only serves original content, but neither this show nor any of the others that were advertised on my screen are by Apple.

Comment: You have most probably purchased that video through the Apple TV app, not the Apple TV+ service which does not sell or rent content. Content, when accessed through Apple TV+, is available only by subscription.

Comment: Purchased from the link that appears above.  Which redirects to the app that I mentioned.  Which isn't the point.  The point is that I paid for it and I want to watch it.  Since they accepted the payment and allowed the download, permissions should not be an issue.  And if the let me read the dialogue (CC) and listen to it, permission apparently is not the problem.

Comment: Sure. However, the more accurately you describe what has transpired, the better help you may get more quickly. The link you have added for the video points to a purchase through the Apple TV app, not the Apple TV+ service, as I surmised. Perhaps the confusion stems from the Apple TV+ service also being provided through the Apple TV app.

Comment: Yeah,the link.  I definitely put it there during the original typing but it somehow disappeared.  Anyway, I didn't say it came from the streaming service, I said the app, and where it came from is not the issue.

Comment: I don't do subscriptions.  As rarely as I buy audio/video/books, one-off is cheaper.  I only went to Apple because I didn't find another source (in an admittedly brief search).  But good point on the tag.  I picked that because `apple-tv" was about the hardware device and `tv.app` did't occur to me.  And I forgot that I have the ability to create a tag (in this case, it was good that I forgot).